# ExpressJs with SQLite: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express, node-sqlite3

I have an ExpressJS Backend that is processes and API POST and using SQLite3 to save the request to the database then I want it to respond with the ID of the recent insert.

However, I get the following error on the endpoint:

`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Here is the endpoint code:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();

const db = new sqlite3.Database(process.env.SQLITE_PATH, err => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to database.');
    }
});

router.post('/edit', function(req, res) {
    const id = req.body.id;
    const name = req.body.name;

    // update
    if (id)
    {
        console.log(name);
        res.json('');
    }

    // create
    db.run('INSERT INTO lines (name) VALUES (?)', [name], function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            res.json(`error inserting record with name ${ name }`);
        }

        // get the last insert id
        console.log(`A row has been inserted with rowid ${ this.lastID }`);

        const response = {
            id: this.lastID,
            name
        }

        res.json(response);
    });
});
```

The Create section is what is giving the error.

Comment: you did not return the response so the script will continue. add return res.json(..)

Comment: Thanks, probably a dumb question but I don't know much node